# using variable in another class

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, encapsulation

Iam creating an android app that has many classes inside the main Java package. The MainActivity class implements Button onClick Listener and do some coding with assigning values to variable x inside the method when button is clicked, now I have class#2 use the same variable x in some other coding. I want the onClick method when it is called to send the variable x value to class#2

```
MainActivityCalss {

    hi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int x = 1;
        }
    });

}

Class2 {

    Method() {
        y = x + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: hi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int x= 1;
        }
    });


Class2{
Method (){
y=x+1;
}
}

Comment: define in that another class the setters and getters for that...

Comment: could you give an example, Iam new to java and android

Comment: Have you tried sending value of x through intents and then save them in next activity in x. ?

Comment: Nop, Iam still digging in java and android, if you can give an example would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define "x" in other class and set it using setter method, and where ever you get it through getter.

```
public class value {
    public static int x;

    public static void set(int value) {
        x = value;
    }

    public static int get() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

And in onclicklistener of mainactivity.

```
hi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        value.set(1);
    }
});
```

In class2

```
 Method() {
        y = value.get()+1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it. So I need to create a third class and to implement those new methods inside it.

Comment: Done, Thanks Again

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new Java class to hold all global variables is a very good idea.

```
public class GlovalVariable{
    public String x;
    public int y;
    // Generate getter/setter methods for all the variables defined here.
}
```

By creating this you will manage a variables very easily. If you want to rename the variable which is used through out the class, this method will make it very easy.